# Kotlin creating a Word class for an 8-bit emulator

Tags: class, kotlin, emulation, cpu-word, 6502

I'm looking for help with a resurrection of a 6502 emulator I wrote in Java many moons ago and now converting to Kotlin. Yes, there's lot out there, but this is my implementation so I could learn how to create emulators and now, how to use Kotlin.

I require a Word class for addresses, i.e.:

```
class Word(initValue: Int = 0x0000) {
    var value = initValue
        get() = field
        set(newValue) {
            field = newValue and 0xFFFF
        }
}
```

I can't extend Int, thus I assume I have an internal copy inside my class (if there's a better way, I'd love to hear it).

Using this:

```
val address = Word()
```

Is trivial and I can use it with lots of `address.value += 123` to move to another location. Further to this, I can add functions to perform Add, Inc, Dec etc.

However, is there a way I can modify the class so I can:

```
address += 123
```

Directly?

I'm not sure how or what the approach is for this? I'd prefer NOT to have a lot of:

```
address.add(123)    or       address.value += 123
```

in my emulator.

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be trying to recreate [`UShort`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-u-short/index.html), so it's probably easier to use that.  (Or even just [`Short`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-short/index.html) if you can handle the signedness.)  If you really needed to write your own, the [`operator`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html) keyword can help.

Comment: Thank you. Did not realise the Unsigned types were there! I've had a play, but not keen on the fact they are experimental and don't quite have all the function I require, such as LowByte and HighByte access. I've gone with the operator override below; which again I wasn't aware of. Many thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Java, Kotlin allows for operator overloading.

Find the [documentation here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html)

From the documentation you can use operator keyword to create overloaded function

```
data class Counter(val dayIndex: Int) {
    operator fun plus(increment: Int): Counter {
        return Counter(dayIndex + increment)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, many thanks! I've just got back in from watching football and work. Just seen this post! The UShort looked rather good and works to some extent. However, I'm not keen on the fact it is still experimental and the fact it doesn't have LowByte() and HighByte() access, therefore I'd need to extend it. Therefore I've gone with the operator overide in my own Word class. It works a treat!!